# Angular keeps throwing error: undefined is not a function at new ngDirective.controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive to create tab style navigation, for fun.
This is the directives:

```
define(['angular'], function (ng) {
var directives = ng.module('directives', []);

/* top navigation tabs */
directives.directive('tabset', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'common/components/directives/templates/tabset.tpl.html'
    };
})
.directive('tab', ['$location', function ($location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            route: '@',
            title: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var route = attrs.route;

            scope.location = $location;
            scope.active = false;

            scope.$watch('location.path()', function (new_route) {
                scope.active = route === new_route;
            });
        },
        templateUrl: 'common/components/directives/templates/tab.tpl.html'
    };
}]);

return directives;
});
```

Angular keeps throwing this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at new ngDirective.controller (http://localhost:8080/uwr-tournament-handler/build/common/vendor/angular/angular.js:14357:5)
at invoke (http://localhost:8080/uwr-tournament-handler/build/common/vendor/angular/angular.js:3000:28)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8080/uwr-tournament-handler/build/common/vendor/angular/angular.js:3012:23)
at http://localhost:8080/uwr-tournament-handler/build/common/vendor/angular/angular.js:4981:24
at http://localhost:8080/uwr-tournament-handler/build/common/vendor/angular/angular.js:4560:17
at forEach (http://localhost:8080/uwr-tournament-handler/build/common/vendor/angular/angular.js:137:20)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/uwr-tournament-handler/build/common/vendor/angular/angular.js:4545:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/uwr-tournament-handler/build/common/vendor/angular/angular.js:4191:15)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/uwr-tournament-handler/build/common/vendor/angular/angular.js:4194:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/uwr-tournament-handler/build/common/vendor/angular/angular.js:4194:13)
```

And I have no idea why. I don't see any `undefined` that I try to use as a function.
Can anyone help?

The error is irregular, but most of the time it is thrown.
Maybe it has something to do with async loading?
It seems to only happen on page load, not while browsing the site.

I use grunt in the background.
I also use requirejs.

Other than that, it seems to work like it should.

tab.tpl.html:

```
<li data-ng-class="{active: active}">
    <a href="#{{route}}">{{title}}</a>
</li>
```

tabset.tpl.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-transclude></ul>
```

Usage:

```
<tabset>
    <tab data-route="/home" data-title="Home"></tab>
    <tab data-route="/tournaments" data-title="Tournaments"></tab>
    <tab data-route="/about" data-title="About"></tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: The thing that stands out is you're $watch-ing a function called "location.path()" instead of a property. Can anyone else confirm if this is doable?

Comment: @MikeRobinson This was a problem long before I did that, but it does work, at least with my testing.

Comment: [http://plnkr.co/edit/YqckKW](http://plnkr.co/edit/YqckKW) I have no problem running it. Can you create a plunker?

Comment: @Daiwei My suspicion is that is has nothing to do with the directive, but I dont know, and the error is complaining about `ngDirective.controller`. Could it be that I don't have an controller?
I'll try to create one, but don't have time right now.

Comment: @kjelelokk do you required this module in another angular.module? Or this is the module you put in `ng-app`? If it is the first case, the problem might be somewhere else.